# spawn-fcgi doesn't start automatically even though has root permission Centos 7

Tags: linux, centos, bash, centos7, service

I have very strange problem I don't know how to solve this. I have spawn-fcgi service only starts if I manually start as root but not with on boot

systemctl enable spawn-cgi  gives me this information I don't know if this error message or just information

[root@www ~]# systemctl enable spawn-fcgi
spawn-fcgi.service is not a native service, redirecting to /sbin/chkconfig.
Executing /sbin/chkconfig spawn-fcgi on

or

chkconfig --levels 235 spawn-fcgi on

Doesn't enable spawn-fgci on boot

Since these solution doesn't work then I did try to make bash script by using root permission to start this service on boot still no joy. I still need to trigger manually

following script works only when I manually trigger, not automatically trigger on boot even though cron has root permission.

Output from command cd /root/ && ./start-awstats-spawn-fgci.sh ..
Starting spawn-fcgi (via systemctl):  [  OK  ]

any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok I solved this problem by using sleep 5m command in my bash script, because it should start spawn-fcgi service after ip bind not before.